# Copying a collection whose name is a number in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, collections, naming

i habe named a collection 222. I want to copy that one but it doesn't work.

```
db.222.find()
2020-08-21T13:37:24.355+0200 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:2
```

I am getting that error message. There should be a way to call columns that starts with a number like in other languages, but I don't know how...

hopefully someone had the same problem earlier and can help me.

best reagards and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [getCollection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/index.html) function.

```
db.getCollection("222").find()
```